# Norm of integral bigger than infimum of norm

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $f \in C^0(\mathbb R,\mathbb R^n)$.

Is it true that $\lVert \int_a^bf(t)dt \rVert_2 \geq \inf_{t \in [a,b]} \lVert f(t)\rVert_2 \cdot (b-a) $ ?

I think it is true for $f \in C^0(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$, here is my proof :

If $f$ doesn't change sign in $[a,b]$, then $\lvert \int_a^bf(t)dt\rvert = \int_a^b\lvert f(t) \rvert dt \geq \inf_{t \in [a,b]}\lvert f(t) \rvert \cdot (b-a). $

If $f$ changes sign in $[a,b]$, then $\inf_{t \in [a,b]}\lvert f(t) \rvert = 0$, and obviously $\int_a^b\lvert f(t) \rvert dt \geq 0$.

This argument doesn't work for $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$, but I was wondering if it is still true (I'm trying to  use it in an exercise).

Comment: Let $f(t)=(\cos t,\sin t).$  Then the integral over $[0,2\pi]$ vanishes but $\|f(t)\|_2=1.$

Comment: Yes that's true thank you.